# Dockerized Dotnet Core 2.1 throws Gdip exception when using Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am using Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore(18.3.0) to convert Html to pdf in Dotnetcore 2.1. It is perfectly working in local environment but when hosted with Docker it throws an error saying,

> {"fileName":"System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer
>   for 'Gdip' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException:
>   Unable to load shared library 'libdl' or one of its dependencies. In
>   order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG
>   environment variable: liblibdl: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory\n   at Interop.Libdl.dlopen(String fileName,
>   Int32 flag)\n   at
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.LoadNativeLibrary()\n   at
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()\n   --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---\n   at
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipNewPrivateFontCollection(IntPtr&
>   fontCollection)\n   at SelectPdf.Lib.ᡜ..ctor()\n   at
>   SelectPdf.Lib.៞..ctor()\n   at SelectPdf.Lib.៞..ctor(ᡏ A_0, ᠝ A_1)\n
>   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜁ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String
>   A_3, Boolean A_4)\n   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(String
>   htmlString)

I have tried by adding these set of lines in Dockerfile, but still having the same error.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base  
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils  
RUN apt-get install -y libgdiplus  
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /usr/lib/gdiplus.dll  
WORKDIR /app  
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Are you trying to host on Windows or Linux based engine?

Comment: I have tried with both.worked none for me.

Comment: Check this open issue on github: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25102

Comment: Thanks Mohsin. I've already followed up those steps but it didn't help. I've raised this to owners of Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore.

Answer (score 20):

I know It is an old question but I encountered this problem lately and I would like to share with my solution.
**Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore do not work on linux**
Just do not. If you already have generated string with html I would advise you to find this nuget: **Haukcode.DinkToPdf** 
To find some tutorials just google **DinkToPdf**. Haukcode is just updated and more docker friendly version.
some dockerfile stuff:

`FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.0 as Base
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y libgdiplus
RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev 
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so/usr/lib/gdiplus.dll
...`

I hope it will help someone :)

Comment: I followed the solution outlined here and got it working: https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI/issues/148 similar but was missing the display setup from X-Server

Comment: I also faced the same problem but the solution was not working for me because i was adding the all install command under build stage but not in publish stage. For multi stage docker file, one should add the install commands under publish stage.

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me. 
I'm running a Debian server, using System.Drawing.Common 4.7.0

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
    libc6-dev \
    libgdiplus \
    libx11-dev \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `libc6-dev` in your Docker container. You can install libc6-dev by running the following command:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev
```

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: In my question I have mentioned the above command did not work for me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Apologies, you need to install libc6-dev. Can you try that? I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am sorry. Still having the same error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Installing libc6-dev had me getting rid of the Dll load exception. But now I have the same exception with kernel32.dll

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? Also, if adding libc6-dev helped, can you upvote this anwer? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem too using iTextSharp 5.5.13.1 and the way I've solved is combine @Frederik Carlier's solution in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libxml2 libgdiplus libc6-dev
```

After that, i've restarted Rancher Container and Rancher User Stack and it works fine.

(Runtime used: FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime)